# Xcode iOS - Rotate/scale UIImageView with an "anchor" at top right?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation, scale

I am building an image editing program that places "stamps" over images.

I've successfully added image views as stamps to a photo and can re-position/scale/rotate these stamps (image views) using pinch gesture recognizers.

However when the stamp gets too small, it becomes impossible to fit two fingers over the stamp to resize or rotate.

I've noticed similar types of apps use some sort of "anchor" or icon at the top-right corner of the stamp's frame that you can drag with one finger that achieves this same scale/rotate effect (as opposed to using pinching gestures).

Is there a specific term for this "anchor" or a term for this kind of scale/rotate procedure? I'm having trouble searching for help on this particular kind of feature.

If anyone might know of any prebuilt classes or links to pages describing how to implement this kind of feature, that would be a huge help!

I am attaching an animated GIF to help illustrate what I am trying to implement.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after I posted this question I checked out some of the Related questions and I stumbled upon a module called ZDStickerView.  After playing around with it I think it will work perfectly for my application.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/zdstickerview